# Einstein's Field Equation via Buckingham Pi Theorem

Tags: general-relativity, dimensional-analysis

I am trying to obtain the field equation using the Buckingham Pi theorem. I was wondering if there is a way to obtain the field equation using dimensions alone from just $G,c,g_{\mu\nu}$, and the Christoffel symbol (representing potential), since potential interactions give rise to fields that have central forces which curve the space time (I haven't used this route below). The following is my go at it:

$$f(R_{\mu\nu},R,g_{\mu\nu},T_{\mu\nu},G,c)=0$$
Where $R_{\mu\nu}$ is the Ricci tensor, $R$ is the Ricci scalar, $T_{\mu\nu}$ is the Stress-Energy tensor, $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the metric tensor, $G$ is the Gravitational constant, and $c$ is the speed of light.

Now, we have $6$ physical variables and $3$ independent dimensions, i.e., $M, L,$ and $T$, which gives $p-n = k=3$ dimensionless constants.

Setting the first dimensionless constant as: $\Pi_1=g_{\mu\nu}^aG^cc^cT_{\mu\nu}$, we obtain the first constant to be $\Pi_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}}}\frac{G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu}$, and similarly  $\Pi_2=g_{\mu\nu}R$, and  $\Pi_3=g_{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}$.

The functional form can be expressed as:  $\Pi_1=f(\Pi_2,\Pi_3)$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}}}\frac{G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu}=f(g_{\mu\nu}R,g_{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu})$$

The above equation correctly resembles the dependence of the Stress Energy tensor. Firstly, is this correct? How do I obtain the field equation from this form (i.e., what relations am I to draw from the above form to obtain an explicit equation)?

**Edit:**

By considering a potential, $V=1/r$, in a space with energy density, $\rho_{vacuum}=\frac{ML^2T^{-2}}{L^3}$ which would cause a curvature, $R=L^{-2}$ (Since we consider $3D$ space to be embedded in a $4$D space with $4$ coordinates), we can get invariants: $\Pi_1=\frac{G\rho_{vacuum}}{c^4V^2}$ and $\Pi_2=\frac{R}{V^2}$. 
Equating these we obtain: $$\frac{G\rho_{vacuum}}{c^4}=R$$
By Lorentz invariance (in vacuum): $<T_{\mu\nu}>=-\rho_{vacuum}g_{\mu\nu}$. Thus, upon multiplying the metric tensor on the LHS and RHS, we obtain the form:$$\frac{GT_{\mu\nu}}{c^4}=-Rg_{\mu\nu}$$. Is this a better analysis?

Comment: This is wrong. You completely disregard the fact that $g_{\mu\nu}$, $R_{\mu\nu}$ are tensors and EFE must be tensor equation. There is no such thing as $\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}}$ and $g_{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}$

Comment: Yeah I do realize that, is it possibly a mistake in the considerations I made of what physical variables are to be considered?

Comment: You can probably push this a little further but it's kind of like... reasoning from the conclusion, I guess? If you already believe that gravity is determined by curvature (as you did in the very first step) then you're basically already there.